# No me muestra la opción de Crear Clase Scala en IDE IntelliJ Idea

Tags: intellij-idea, scala

Buen dia Comunidad.

soy nuevo en el mundo de Scala, pero estoy instalando mi IDE de IntelliJ, cuando creo el nuevo proyecto ya  de Scala y me voy a `Proyecto/src/scala` cuando le  doy click derecho solo me muestra crear `clase  java` y  no **crear clase Scala.**

Ya instale el plugin de Scala y tengo igual el set instalado. También ya tengo mi  jdk  en la versión 1.8

tengo la version de scala

version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.11.6"

¿Alguien sabe como habilito la opción ?

Comment: Creaste un proyecto Scala o un Proyecto SBT?. Pudiste ver la documentación oficial: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/run-debug-and-test-scala.html? Pudiste correr el REPL de Scala por la consola para ver si está ok?

Answer (score 1):

En primer lugar, si no lo has hecho, deberías reiniciar el IDE una vez instalado el plug-in de Scala.

Por otro lado, al crear el proyecto, debes seguir los siguientes pasos:
`File` > `New` > `Project`

A la izquierda seleccionas la opción `Scala` y, de entre las opciones que te da, seleccionas `IDEA`. Al pulsar en `Next` te pedirá nombre del proyecto, ubicación, así como el JDK y el SDK, que tendrás que especificar.

Una vez creado el proyecto correctamente deberías estar habilitado para crear tus clases y paquetes dentro del directorio `src`.

Pruébalo y nos cuentas!

Comment: Pero, de todos modos Scala se ejecuta sobre la máquina virtual de Java. Scala necesita algo de Java.

Comment: Efectivamente, se necesita el JDK instalado, que además debe estar seleccionado como indiqué en el anterior comentario.

Answer (score 0):

Me sucedió lo mismo y lo resolvi volviendo a refrescar las dependencias, pero antes solo para recapitular lo que se debe hacer es:

1. -Descargar, instalar y poner el SDK 8 u 11 en las Variables de Entorno
2. -Descargar SCALA y poner en las Variables de Entorno
3. -Descargar SBT y poner en las Variables de Entorno

después en consola o en la terminal checas que cada uno este instalado adecuadamente, y ahora si puedes empezar con tu proyecto, si creaste el proyecto antes de hacer todo esto, solo refresca las dependencias de sbt.